# AWS deployment missing my PWA build files

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, progressive-web-apps

I am using AWS (the Amplify console) to deploy my Angular 8 (PWA) app. Deployments have stopped working properly, and it seems that Amplify is not deploying all the files in my distribution build.

To deploy, I create a bundle with `$ ng build --prod`

This works without errors.

I then drag and drop this bundle into my AWS (Amplify) console. The deployment works, but then the app shows the errors below.

I have been deploying this way for several weeks without problem. 2 days ago--while not changing any of my app's settings or amplify settings as far as I can tell--**the deployed app would fail to show certain component pages**. And those pages would show this error:

```
Syntax Error: Unexpected Token '<' 

Error: Uncaught (in promise): ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 5 failed.
```

(chunk number varies depending on which component I try to click on)

I also get an error saying:

```
Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: https://www.[app].com/assets/icons/icon-144x144.png (Download error or resource isn't a valid image)
```

It seems that AWS is saying certain files (like the icon file) do not exist in the deployment. But, these files clearly exist in the bundle that I am uploading when I view the folder locally.

The problem also seems to grow with each deployment. I just re-uploaded the same bundle as before, and it is now showing this error for more components (even though it is the same exact bundle(!))

What could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this problem is not fully clear, but it seems like creating a zip file of the build, deploying that to S3, and then on the amplify console call the build from S3.

More info on that is [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/584#issuecomment-613570006).